# Installing GruntJS on Ubuntu 13.04 does not run client (same for all NPM -g modules)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu

Okay here's probably an easy one for anyone familiar with Ubuntu.

I have installed NodeJS (v.0.10.10) and NPM. I ran:

```
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

and

```
sudo npm install -g grunt
```

(in every combination)

but although everything seems to install successfully, i.e. I see in */usr/lib/node_modules* the grunt-cli folder and I navigate to the bin, and see the grunt exe, when I try to type grunt, I don't get any errors, but just nothing except the next command line prompt.

BTW - I've tried installing jasmine-node globally as well with the same results.

I installed npm and nodejs from Chris Lea's PPA.

Comment: SOLVED: solution was to uninstall node:

    sudo apt-get remove node

Comment: sweet, can you post that as an answer to your question, accept it as the official answer, and that way people know not to reply :)

Answer (score 6):

The solution was to uninstall the "node" package:

```
sudo apt-get remove node
```

Note: This is a completely different package than the stable release version of Node.js.